# rails lib 以下のファイルの再読み込みについて

Tags: ruby-on-rails

rails では、app/以下のファイルは変更すると、rails sを行わなくても自動的に再読み込みされ、結果がコンソールに反映されると思います。

ここでわからなかったのですが、lib/以下も同じ様に反映させることはできないのでしょうか、機能を切り分けて作成したファイルがlib/~~.rbとあるのですが、そちらを変更した時には結果が即座に反映されないことに気づきました。

なにかアドバイス頂けると嬉しいです、、

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths` に、 rails が自動的にいい感じにクラス・モジュールを読み込むディレクトリのリストが格納されています。

rails 4 -> 5 -> 6 の間でここら辺はまた進化していたような記憶があり、今の最新版で正しい方法が何かが若干怪しいですが、少なくとも自分の手元では、以下のようにすると任意のディレクトリを rails の autoload paths に追加できそうだ、と思っています。

`config/application.rb` にて:

```
# 略
module YourApplicationName
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # 略

    config.autoload_paths += ['lib']
  end
end
```

ただ、個人的には、 `lib` 自身を autoload_path に使うのは、規約(convention)に反している気がするので、 `lib/my_classes` など、適当にディレクトリを作成して、そのパス(この場合は `lib/my_classes`)を上記のように autoload_paths に追記するのが良いと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます！

すごく分かりやすいです、、

一点だけ質問してもよろしいでしょうか、、

>　 lib 自身を autoload_path に使うのは、規約(convention)に反している気がするので

こちらの規約とは、どういった考え方でしょうか？

lib自身を設定するのは、それに反していて、
lib/my_classesなどのディレクトリを挟むことで反しなくなる、というそのあたりについても、お手数ですが教えて頂けると嬉しいです。

Comment: lib フォルダは、　assets や　tasks などがデフォルトで作成されていたとおもっており、なので、 rails 的には、　lib の下にまた一階層以上のディレクトリを作成して、それに対して　autoload_path を指定するのが、　rails 的なのではないか、という意図です。

Comment: ありがとうございます！

rails的という所が勉強不足でまだわかりませんが、調べて見たいと思います。

本当にありがとうございます！